# Raspberry Pi WiFi Access Point using DHCP configuration from router

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi

I’d like to turn my Raspberry Pi 3 model B into a WiFi access point which uses DHCP and other configurations given by the router, and exclusively acts like a dumb access point, providing entry to the network. Every guide I’ve come across for building said project sets up a DHCP server on the Pi, and uses NAT & IP forwarding between the different interfaces to make it work, but this only creates a new network inside the original one. I would like to have my Pi be like a commercial access point, just plug it in and create an entry point to the network. Thank you in advance ;)

PS: I’m using Raspbian Stretch Lite Kernel 4.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using hostapd and bridging network interfaces.

While you don't mention the distro, the general instructions are the same.

Please see: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-setting-wireless-access-point/

FYI the wifi dongle you use must support AP mode for this to work.